# Database query and Java

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm studying at a project about the creation of simple web application. 
I'm creating a webapp about an Hotel and I have a problem about the reservation of a room.
I have 3 kind of rooms and I want when someone book a room, another one can't book the same room in the same period.
The problem is about this kind of control.
I have write this code:

**UPDATE CODE AFTER AN ANSWER**

```
 Statement  st =  con.createStatement();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        out.println("connection successfull");
        int total = 0;
        ResultSet rs3 = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM reservation WHERE idRoom = '" + idRoom + 
                "' AND ('" + arrivaldate + "' >= arrivaldate AND '" + arrivaldate + "' <= departuredate) OR ('" + departuredate + "' >= arrivaldate "
                + "AND '" + departuredate + "' <= departuredate)");
        rs3.next(); // You'll ever have only one row
        total = rs3.getInt("total");


       /* String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reservation WHERE idRoom = '" + idRoom + 
                "' AND ('" + arrivaldate + "' >= arrivaldate AND '" + arrivaldate + "' <= departuredate) OR ('" + departuredate + "' >= arrivaldate "
                        + "AND '" + departuredate + "' <= departuredate)" ;

        */

       // ResultSet rs2  = stmt.executeQuery(check);
        out.println("<h1> Stringa check eseguito </h1>");


        if( total  > 0) { // THIS DOESN't WORK OF COURSE    
            response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
        }
        else {
         st.executeUpdate("insert into reservation (login,email,typeroom,idRoom,arrivaldate,departuredate)values ('"+login+"','"+email+"','"+typeroom+"','"+idRoom+"','"+arrivaldate+"','"+departuredate+"')");
        }
```

But it doesn't work properly because it lets me to book the same room in the same data. 
How can I do in your opinion? Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you totally ignore your total:

```
while(rs3.next()){
   rs3.getInt("total");
}
```

Should be:

```
rs3.next(); // You'll ever have only one row
total = rs3.getInt("total");
```

And second, never ever use concatenations in your queries:

```
ResultSet rs3 = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM reservation WHERE idRoom = '" + idRoom + 
                    "' AND ('" + arrivaldate + "' >= arrivaldate AND '" + arrivaldate + "' <= departuredate) OR ('" + departuredate + "' >= arrivaldate "
                    + "AND '" + departuredate + "' <= departuredate)");
```

Always use PreparedStatements instead:

```
 PreparedStatement ps = stmt.prepareStatement( "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM reservation WHERE idRoom = ? AND (? >= arrivaldate AND ? <= departuredate) OR (? >= arrivaldate AND ? <= departuredate)");

int c = 0;
ps.setInt(++c, idRoom);
ps.setDate(++c, arrivaldate);
ps.setDate(++c, departuredate);
ps.setDate(++c, arrivaldate);
ps.setDate(++c, departuredate);

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
// And your usual code here
```

Comment: Always happy to help.

Comment: Whit the first advice you have answer my question, but i don't have understand well your second answer! I update my code in the first post :)